# Akeneo product variant import information possible?

Tags: php, database, file, import, akeneo

I am using the PIM Akeneo and try to import information to my products. The product model I want to enrich is a special perfume. My variant is "scent".

Is there a possibility to import the respective description, EAN, SKU etc. to the related variant?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know what is possible to do with an import and what is the expected format is to:

- Create the product in the state you expect them to be after the import
- Launch the export profile corresponding to your import

As the output format is the same as the input one, you will see what is expected by Akeneo PIM